# Using Drools with Glassfish server

Tags: glassfish, drools

I am trying to use simple drools rule  with my dynamic web app. I created my servlet and now trying to integrate my rule. But it gives me error at this line

```
 RuleBase ruleBase = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase();

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.drools.util.ChainedProperties.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Z)V
    at org.drools.RuleBaseConfiguration.init(RuleBaseConfiguration.java:395)
    at org.drools.RuleBaseConfiguration.<init>(RuleBaseConfiguration.java:251)
    at org.drools.common.AbstractRuleBase.<init>(AbstractRuleBase.java:147)
    at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooRuleBase.<init>(ReteooRuleBase.java:160)
    at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooRuleBase.<init>(ReteooRuleBase.java:137)
    at org.drools.RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase(RuleBaseFactory.java:87)
    at org.drools.RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase(RuleBaseFactory.java:75)
    at org.drools.RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase(RuleBaseFactory.java:38)
    at server.HelloServlet.runRules(HelloServlet.java:148)
    at server.HelloServlet.NewRule(HelloServlet.java:181)
    at server.HelloServlet.doGet(HelloServlet.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
```

And Here my  Helloservlet.java class

@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@EJB HelloBean bean;

@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory emf;




/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public HelloServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.print("<html><body><title>servlet page</title>");
    out.print("<h1> " +request.getServletPath() + "</h1>");
    out.println("<h2>" + bean.sayHello("nabiyin") + "</h2>");
MyUser user=(MyUser)emf.createEntityManager().createQuery("select u from MyUser u").getResultList().get(0);

try {
NewRule();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("HATAAAAA");
    e.printStackTrace();
}




    out.print("age: " + user.getAge());

    if (user.getAge()<23) {
        out.println("hello");
    }

    out.print("</html></body>");
}

public void runRules(String[] rules, Object... facts)
throws Exception
{       
    RuleBase ruleBase = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase();
    PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();       

    for(String ruleFile : rules)
    {
        System.out.println("Loading file: "+ruleFile);
        builder.addPackageFromDrl(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(ruleFile)));
    }

    Package pkg = builder.getPackage();       
    ruleBase.addPackage(pkg);

    WorkingMemory workingMemory
        = ruleBase.newStatefulSession();   

    for(Object fact : facts)
    {
        System.out.println("Inserting fact: "+fact);
        workingMemory.insert(fact);
    }

    workingMemory.fireAllRules();
}


public  void NewRule()
throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("New rule started");

   Number n1=3 , n2=1, n3=4 , n4=1 ,n5=5; 
   new HelloServlet().runRules(
          new String[]{"model/NewRule.drl"},
            n1,n2,n3,n4,n5);

    System.out.println("New rule finisheds");
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the rule engine as a singelton EJB in your web application, to avoid every web session creates its own rule engine instance (for the simple demo above not important).

Can you try to work with the current libraries and try again. (maybe current is the wrong word, but there is a difference!)
Look at the samples in the current drools distribution or this simple sample: http://javadude.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/drools-expert-read-rules-from-string-and-database/

```
..
import org.drools.KnowledgeBase;
import org.drools.KnowledgeBaseFactory;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilder;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory;
import org.drools.builder.ResourceType;
import org.drools.definition.KnowledgePackage;
..
```

(Experts might correct if I am wrong)